# sum of each 24 elements in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, multidimensional-array, sum

I have a 3D matrix (70x51x8760) (longitude x latitude x time in hours) and I want the sum of each 24 (elements) hours. My new matrix will have this dimension (70x51x365).

any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you reach a situation where the third dimension isn't divisible by 24 then you can do this:

```
n = 24;
subs = ceil((1:size(A,3))/n)

for ii = 1:size(A, 1)
    for jj = 1:size(A,2)

        result(ii,jj,:) = accumarray(subs', squeeze(A(ii,jj,:)));

    end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

`reshape` into the 4<sup>th</sup> dimension, `sum` into the 3<sup>rd</sup>, and `squeeze`:

```
B = squeeze( sum(reshape(A, size(A,1),size(A,2),24,[]), 3));
```

Comment: or: `reshape(A,size(A,1),size(A,2),[],24)` for auto-determination f the third dimension.

Comment: also I would use `permute(.., [1 2 4 3])` instead of `squeeze` to get rid of the singleton dimension (IMO being explicit is better)

Comment: btw it should be `reshape(A,size(A,1),size(A,2),24,[])` (and the same flip for Rody's version)

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, here is the for-loop version:

```
A = rand(70,51,8760);  % sample data 3D matrix
n = 24;                % group every n-pages and sum across the 3rd dimension

% calculate starting indices
sz = size(A);
ind = 1:n:sz(3);

% compute the sums in each group of pages
B = zeros(sz(1),sz(2),numel(ind));
for k=1:numel(ind)
    B(:,:,k) = sum(A(:,:,ind(k):ind(k)+n-1), 3);
end
```

The above assumes that `size(A,3)` is evenly divisible by `n`. Of course it could be adjusted if that's not the case by processing the first `fix(size(A,3)/n)*n` slices as before, then doing the remaining pages using one last iteration.

---

You could compare the above code against [@RodyOldenhuis's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21261964/97160):

```
B2 = permute(sum(reshape(A,sz(1),sz(2),n,[]),3), [1 2 4 3]);
assert(isequal(B,B2))
```

*(In my tests, this was faster than the for-loop, but not by much)*

---

I also managed to fully vectorize [@Dan's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21262194/97160) into a single [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) call:

```
[I,J,K] = ndgrid(1:sz(1),1:sz(2),1:sz(3));
B3 = accumarray([I(:) J(:) ceil(K(:)./n)], A(:));
assert(isequal(B,B3))
```

*(Warning: this version is memory-intensive, not to mention much slower than the other solutions)*